# PDF - Auto adjust for mobile?

Tags: pdf

Does anyone know if there is a function in PDF's to allow them to auto-adjust the view depending on whether it is on a desktop or mobile? Or even by screen size?

I am looking to prepare PDF material for distribution, however, on the user group includes a mix of desktop and mobile, so instead of creating two PDFs I would like to have a single PDF which adapts to the users screen?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with PDF files up to PDF version 1.7, the most commonly used on out there.

PDF 2.0 which was released three years ago has such a feature but it depends on the viewer implementing it and the PDF writer correctly annotating the PDF. I guess there are PDF viewers out there that can already do this but I'm not specifically aware of any.

If I were you, I would write the document in a format like LaTeX that can easily be converted to both kinds of PDFs, one for desktop and one for mobile.